# Unwanted double backslashes in print output for "join" (Python 3.7.3)

Tags: python-3.7

I am using Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) and would like to use **"join"** to construct a list of delimiters for dividing one huge text file into individual files. The .txt file is the OCR version of a book, and the pages are separated by the following string:

"----- [page number] / 1494 ----- "

1494 stands for the total number of pages, so I need 1494 delimiters, covering the whole range from 1 to 1494.

As part of a longer script, I wrote this **input** to create the list of delimiters:

```
import os
import os.path
from os.path import dirname, join
import re
chunk_count=0
page_range=range(1, 1495)
delimiters=[]
results=[]
search_terms=["insul", "insel", "insuln", "inseln", "insula", "insulae"]
in_file="C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\ACADEMIA\\Insularity in early modern Europe\\Hederich_SchulLexikon_cleaned.txt"
out_directory="C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\ACADEMIA\\Insularity in early modern Europe\\Hederich_Lexikon_chunks"

with open(in_file, encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
    data = f.read()
    for x in page_range:
        delimiter=join('----- ', str(x),' / 1494 ----- ')
        delimiters.append(delimiter)
    print(delimiters[:5])
```

The **output** I am getting is:

```
['----- \\1\\ / 1494 ----- ', '----- \\2\\ / 1494 ----- ', '----- \\3\\ / 1494 ----- ', '----- \\4\\ / 1494 ----- ', '----- \\5\\ / 1494 ----- ']
```

So all my delimiters have double backslashes before and after the page numbers, and I cannot figure out why. What did I miss? Thanks so much for you advice!

Comment: Your delimiters don't actually have *double* backslashes, they're just a single backslash. Just like your text strings do not actually all start and end with a character `'`. It's how Python shows strings in this representation.

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join` is for joining directories with `os.path.sep` (`'\\'` on Windows).  You want `str.join`, which is a method on strings.  But you don't really need `join`, just a format string and a list comprehension:

```
>>> delimiters = [f'----- {page} / 1494 ----- ' for page in range(1,1495)]
>>> delimiters[:5]
['----- 1 / 1494 ----- ', '----- 2 / 1494 ----- ', '----- 3 / 1494 ----- ', '----- 4 / 1494 ----- ', '----- 5 / 1494 ----- ']
```

Answer (score 0):

[`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) must be from an *iterable*, which means you have to give it a list, set, dictionary, etc.

Try the `''.join(list)` syntax:

```py
page_range=range(1, 1495)
delimiters=[]
for x in page_range:
    delimiter=''.join(['----- ', str(x),' / 1494 ----- '])
    delimiters.append(delimiter)
print(delimiters[:5])
```

```
['----- 1 / 1494 ----- ',
 '----- 2 / 1494 ----- ',
 '----- 3 / 1494 ----- ',
 '----- 4 / 1494 ----- ',
 '----- 5 / 1494 ----- ']
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually tried `''.join(list)` first but did not think of square brackets inside the round ones. That fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, consider choosing my or Mark's answer if either of them allowed your code to run.